# Relation of velocity and angular momentum in quantum mechanics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum, velocity

in quantum mechanics (non-relativistic or relativistic), when the angular momentum of the particle change is the velocity effected? 
are we assume the angular momentum equal zero when we determinate the expression of the velocity? (is there any relation said velocity proportional to the angular momentum?)

Answer (score 0):

There was a difference between expected value of $v$ (which was understood as the classical "speed"), and phase $v$(wave propagation).

In H atom when the angular momentum changes you changed the wave functions. But that was at stationary cases(classical $v=0$), so you could change angular momentum without change $v_{classical}$.

Not sure which one you were talking about.

Comment: i talk about the phase velocity , i know that is equal energy over momentum . could we have another term containing the angular momentum ? when the angular momentum change does the velocity change ?

Comment: In quantum things were represented by wave, and operators as observables. Not sure what you meant by angular momentum term. It's not like classical physics.

Comment: Maybe the topic was more related to separation of variables.